# Install KDE on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: package-management, kde

I've got trouble installing the KDE desktop on my Ubuntu. I installed the package kde-standard from the Ubuntu Software Center and rebooted the computer. The login screen is now different and more KDE like, but the desktop stayed the same. It's still the normal Ubuntu desktop.

Do I need to install any other packages besides kde-standard?

Comment: In the login screen, there is an option to select which desktop environment to boot into. For the Oxygen there, it should be a blue down-arrow. Can you try manually selecting the KDE environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the package `kubuntu-desktop` if you want the entire KDE environment. If you only want the looks and will settle for using GNOME applications or what came with `kde-standard`, install `plasma-desktop`. Both install the environment you're looking for, but `kubuntu-desktop` is more thorough and complete. The image below shows what the desktop roughly looks like when first run (minus the windows and KRunner at the top, those you start yourself. :) )[image: KDE4 First Run]

Please not that installing `kubuntu-desktop` will change your boot logo and shutdown logo to this:
[image: Kubuntu Boot Screen]

You decide which package you prefer to install.